# How to return the first column's row value based on a value comparison on another column in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm fairly new to the C# world and need help figuring out a solution. I'm writing a program that contains a Data Table that is formatted like the following:

| Return | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| C | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| D | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

I have the user input which column they want to search in, say "300", and they also input a number. Assuming the search is done top to bottom, if that number is less than the first value, it should return the first column value of that same row.

So, lets continue with "300" as the search column. If the user enters 4.7, I want to be returned "C" since 4.7 is less than or equal to 5. The values in the 100-400 columns will always be in order from lowest to highest. I know this has to be possible, but the last few hours trying to figure out how to to logical comparisons to values in giving me a hard time and any help or direction is appreciated.

I should note that I'm using this data table in another function to pretty much do the opposite, so I'd like to not restructure this data table since I've already spent the time creating it.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far at making the attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ, I writed a console project with your example, in this i use LINQ and Math Floor,Ceiling and round you can use with your business logic:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
            dt.Columns.Add("Return");
            dt.Columns.Add("100");
            dt.Columns.Add("200");
            dt.Columns.Add("300");
            dt.Columns.Add("400");
            dt.Rows.Add("Un", 1, 2, 3, 4);
            dt.Rows.Add("B", 2, 3, 4, 5);
            dt.Rows.Add("C", 3, 4, 5, 6);
            dt.Rows.Add("D", 4, 5, 6, 7);

        Again:
            Console.WriteLine($"Write Column[100, 200, 300, 400]:");
            var SearchColumn = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"Write value:");
            double val;
            bool isDouble = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out val);
            if (!isDouble) goto notShow;
            string returned;

            // Return First 5 for 4.7, Return "C"
            returned = dt.Select().FirstOrDefault(o => int.Parse(o[SearchColumn].ToString()) == Math.Floor(val))[0].ToString();

            Console.WriteLine($"Math.Floor: {returned}");

            // Return First 4 for 4.7, Return "B"
            returned = dt.Select().FirstOrDefault(o => int.Parse(o[SearchColumn].ToString()) == Math.Ceiling(val))[0].ToString(); ;
            Console.WriteLine($"Math.Ceiling: {returned}");

            // Return First 5 for 4.7, Return "C"
            returned = dt.Select().FirstOrDefault(o => int.Parse(o[SearchColumn].ToString()) == Math.Round(val))[0].ToString(); ;
            Console.WriteLine($"Math.Round: {returned}\n\n");

            goto Again;
        notShow:
            Console.WriteLine("Error: not is valid");
            goto Again;
        }
}
```

these lines search in the collection of rows and returns the value of the first column:

```
        returned = dt.Select().FirstOrDefault(o => int.Parse(o[SearchColumn].ToString()) == Math.Floor(val))[0].ToString();

        returned = dt.Select().FirstOrDefault(o => int.Parse(o[SearchColumn].ToString()) == Math.Ceiling(val))[0].ToString(); ;

        returned = dt.Select().FirstOrDefault(o => int.Parse(o[SearchColumn].ToString()) == Math.Round(val))[0].ToString(); ;
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ I got all the rows greater than or Equal to input value and the picked the first one. The column values are already in ascending order as per the question.

```
// Create a sample DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable("tbl");
DataColumn dtColumn;
dtColumn = new DataColumn();
dtColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
dtColumn.ColumnName = "Return";
dtColumn.ReadOnly = false;
dtColumn.Unique = true;
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);


dtColumn = new DataColumn();
dtColumn.DataType = typeof(Int32);
dtColumn.ColumnName = "100";
dtColumn.ReadOnly = false;
dtColumn.Unique = true;
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

dtColumn = new DataColumn();
dtColumn.DataType = typeof(Int32);
dtColumn.ColumnName = "200";
dtColumn.ReadOnly = false;
dtColumn.Unique = true;
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

dtColumn = new DataColumn();
dtColumn.DataType = typeof(Int32);
dtColumn.ColumnName = "300";
dtColumn.ReadOnly = false;
dtColumn.Unique = true;
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr["Return"] = "A";
dr["100"] = 1;
dr["200"] = 2;
dr["300"] = 3;

dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr["Return"] = "B";
dr["100"] = 2;
dr["200"] = 3;
dr["300"] = 4;

dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr["Return"] = "C";
dr["100"] = 3;
dr["200"] = 4;
dr["300"] = 5;

dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr["Return"] = "D";
dr["100"] = 4;
dr["200"] = 5;
dr["300"] = 6;

double inputVal = 4.7;
// The Column data is already ordered , as mentioned in the question
var t1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r1 => r1.Field<int>("300") >= inputVal)  // all records greater than the input value
                          .Select(a => a[0]).ToList() // select value from first column
                          .FirstOrDefault();  // the closest one
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I think I've got it (seems to work) but I'm posting my solution for review. Maybe it's not the best way to go about it?
>
> ```
> var returnValue = string.Empty;
>
> foreach (DataColumn col in Table503().Columns) {
>    if (col.ColumnName == searchColumn) {
>        for (var i = 0; i < Table503().Rows.Count; i++) {
>            foreach (DataRow row in Table503().Rows) {
>                if (searchValue <= Convert.ToDouble(row[searchColumn])) {
>                    returnValue = Convert.ToString(row["Return"]);
>                    break;
>                }   
>            }
>        }    
>    }
> }
>
> return returnValue;
> ```